# i am getting error 4051 mql4 using webrequest

Tags: httpwebrequest, webrequest, mql4, mql5

this is my code I am trying to send a PUT http request to this endpoint but Im getting error 4051 and also status code is -1 and it is not even reaching to the server.

```
void OnStart(){
   double equity = AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_EQUITY);
   Alert("equity: ",equity);
   Alert("INIT_SUCCEEDED: ",INIT_SUCCEEDED);
   char post[], result[];

   string headers ;
   
   string obj     = "{\"balance\":200000,\"minimumBalance\":200000,\"equity\":200000,\"minimumEquity\":200000,\"dateTime\":\"2023-01-15T23:45:00.000Z\"}"; 

   StringToCharArray( obj, post, 0, StringLen(obj) ); // Must specify string length;
 
   int res = WebRequest( "PUT",
                         "http://localhost:8000/api/user/add-equity-balance/1",
                          "",
                          NULL,
                          10000,
                          post,
                          ArraySize( post ),
                          result,
                          headers
                          );
   Alert( "Status code: " , res, ", error: ", GetLastError() );
   Alert( "Server response: ", CharArrayToString( result ) );
   Alert("Server headers: ", headers);

 }
```

I just need to send this PUT request

Answer (score 0):

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                         aads.mq4 |
//|                                  Copyright 2023, MetaQuotes Ltd. |
//|                                             https://www.mql5.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2023, MetaQuotes Ltd."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict

input string mesaj="deneme";
input string sunucuAdres="http://deneme.ipekbilgisayar.org"; //Internet Adres
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnStart()
  {
//---
   CagriGonder(mesaj);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CagriGonder(string Mesaj)
  {
   string cookie=NULL,headers;
   char post[],result[];
   string header="Content-Type: application/text";
   StringToCharArray(Mesaj,post,0,StringLen(Mesaj));
   ResetLastError();

   int timeout=20000;
   int res=WebRequest("POST",sunucuAdres,header,timeout,post,result,headers);

   Print(CharArrayToString(result));
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Example